# Flyway error on dependent type declarations within package declaration DDL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, flyway

I'm wondering why flyway cannot execute this package declaration. What should I change?
EDIT: SOLVED.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE "POSITION_REPORTING"."POSREP_FLYWAY_TEST" AS 

 TYPE FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER IS RECORD
 (
    VERSION_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(100),
    VERSION_NOTES   VARCHAR2(100)
 );
 
 TYPE FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER_TAB IS TABLE OF FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER;

END POSREP_FLYWAY_TEST;
```

The code does execute from SQL-Developer without a problem. Flyway tells me it cannot execute the second type declaration. This type depends on the first type so my assumption is that some kind of commit is missing. I do not know where to add that within a package declaration though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does Flyway work for any other stored PL/SQL? I just found [the documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle) and it only mentions support for *"Standard SQL syntax with statement delimiter"* and *"PL/SQL blocks starting with DECLARE or BEGIN and finishing with END; /"*.

Comment: In the comments on the answer below you see that @lukasz-szozda migrated this code successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add separator `/`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE "POSITION_REPORTING"."POSREP_FLYWAY_TEST"
AS 
 TYPE FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER IS RECORD
 (
    VERSION_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(100),
    VERSION_NOTES   VARCHAR2(100)
 );


TYPE FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER_TAB IS TABLE OF FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER;

END "POSREP_FLYWAY_TEST";
/
```

Comment: You're right, that one got lost in my code here. But it is in the flyway script I used - this is something SQL-Developer automatically adds on the export. So your answer does not solve my problem. My assumption is that I would have to add some slashlike stuff between the two declarations.

Comment: @JohanSteunenberg Please post your entire code + exact error message.

Comment: You posted my complete code. Here's the error mesage:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 900
Message    : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Location   : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Line       : 22
Statement  :    TYPE FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER_TAB IS TABLE OF FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Comment: @JohanSteunenberg Strange I just run exact code and everything is migrated successfully.

Comment: in that case I will have to look for privilege issues or some weird configuration issues in our oracle/jenkins/flyway setup. The first step I am questioning now is the word 'editionable' - the next run is without that keyword.

Comment: SOLVED!! The keyword 'EDITIONABLE' was the issue! It jumped me in the face when I saw your rewrite, thanks a lot, @lLukaszSzozda

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'EDITIONABLE' was not accepted in our setup. 
This worked:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE "POSITION_REPORTING"."POSREP_FLYWAY_TEST"
AS 
  TYPE FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER IS RECORD
  (
    VERSION_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(100),
    VERSION_NOTES   VARCHAR2(100)
  );


  TYPE FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER_TAB IS TABLE OF FLYWAY_REPORT_HEADER;

END "POSREP_FLYWAY_TEST";
/
```